# wix burn RemotePayload doesn't work

Tags: wix, burn

In my bundle i have code like this:

```
<?define RoboMongoUrl ="http://robomongo.org/files/windows/Robomongo-0.8.4-RC2-i386.exe"?>

        <ExePackage Id="RoboMongo"
                        DisplayName="RoboMongo"
                        Cache="no"
                        Compressed="no"
                        PerMachine="yes"
                        Permanent="no"
                        Vital="yes"
                        Name="redist\Robomongo-0.8.4-RC2-i386.exe"
                        DownloadUrl="$(var.RoboMongoUrl)"
                        InstallCondition="ComponentSelect_5"
                        InstallCommand='/Action=Install '
                        UninstallCommand="/Action=Uninstall "
                        RepairCommand ="/Action=Repair"
                        DetectCondition="RoboMongoInstanceFound64 OR RoboMongoInstanceFound">

                        <RemotePayload Description="Программа администрирования MongoDB" 
                        Version ="0.8.4.2"
                            ProductName="RoboMongo"
                            Hash="71C17E48BC32304FA8724FFA7CA1C4C08891BC97" Size="7141182" />

        </ExePackage>
```

It compiles ok. But when i try to install, i get an error in log.

```
[04E0:0690][2013-11-19T16:27:41]i201: Planned package: NetFx40Web, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[04E0:0690][2013-11-19T16:27:41]i201: Planned package: SQLExpressx64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[04E0:0690][2013-11-19T16:27:41]i201: Planned package: SQLExpressx86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[04E0:0690][2013-11-19T16:27:41]i201: Planned package: MongoDB, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[04E0:0690][2013-11-19T16:27:41]i201: Planned package: RoboMongo, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: None
[04E0:0690][2013-11-19T16:27:41]i201: Planned package: Server, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: Yes, dependency: None
[04E0:0690][2013-11-19T16:27:41]i201: Planned package: MWP, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: Yes, dependency: None
[04E0:0690][2013-11-19T16:27:41]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[04E0:0690][2013-11-19T16:27:41]i300: Apply begin
[04A8:01A0][2013-11-19T16:27:42]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[04A8:01A0][2013-11-19T16:27:49]i361: Created a system restore point.
[04E0:0690][2013-11-19T16:27:49]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\DOCUME~1\alex\LOCALS~1\Temp\{e0fb3d52-7a6a-40d4-a9ac-3f469271a9b3}\.be\FullInstallationBoot.exe' to: 'C:\Documents and Settings\alex\Local Settings\Application Data\Package Cache\{e0fb3d52-7a6a-40d4-a9ac-3f469271a9b3}\FullInstallationBoot.exe'
[04E0:0690][2013-11-19T16:27:49]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {e0fb3d52-7a6a-40d4-a9ac-3f469271a9b3}, version: 1.0.0.0
[04E0:00EC][2013-11-19T16:27:49]w343: Prompt for source of package: RoboMongo, payload: RoboMongo, path: E:\redist\Robomongo-0.8.4-RC2-i386.exe
[04E0:00EC][2013-11-19T16:27:49]e054: Failed to resolve source for file: E:\redist\Robomongo-0.8.4-RC2-i386.exe, error: 0x80070002.
[04E0:00EC][2013-11-19T16:27:49]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed while prompting for source (original path 'E:\redist\Robomongo-0.8.4-RC2-i386.exe').
[04E0:00EC][2013-11-19T16:27:49]e313: Failed to acquire payload: RoboMongo to working path: C:\DOCUME~1\alex\LOCALS~1\Temp\{e0fb3d52-7a6a-40d4-a9ac-3f469271a9b3}\RoboMongo, error: 0x80070002.
[04E0:0690][2013-11-19T16:27:49]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
[04E0:0690][2013-11-19T16:27:49]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {e0fb3d52-7a6a-40d4-a9ac-3f469271a9b3}
[04E0:0690][2013-11-19T16:27:49]i352: Removing cached bundle: {e0fb3d52-7a6a-40d4-a9ac-3f469271a9b3}, from path: C:\Documents and Settings\alex\Local Settings\Application Data\Package Cache\{e0fb3d52-7a6a-40d4-a9ac-3f469271a9b3}\
[04E0:0690][2013-11-19T16:27:49]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070002, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[04E0:0690][2013-11-19T16:27:49]i300: Apply begin
[04A8:01A0][2013-11-19T16:27:49]i360: Creating a system restore point.
```

It looks like it doesn't even try to download package from web. It is a bit confusing. Does anybody know what is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your BA needs to handle OnResolveSource to ask the Burn engine to download packages that don't exist locally.

Comment: Thank you a lot. You actually rescued me.